# globalize2 - extract translation for specified locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize2

Is there any possibility to extract globalize2 translation for specified locale without setting

```
I18n.locale = :ru
```

as i know - i can extract ALL translations using

```
model.translations
```

but maybe there are simplest way to extract only for one language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a pretty simple plugin that will do this for you:
http://github.com/tomash/easy_globalize2_accessors

```
 class Product
    translates :title, :description
    globalize_accessors :pl, :en, :de
  end
```

will automatically give you accessors like:

```
product.title_en # => "English title"
product.title_de # => "German title"
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your table is called *mytable*: Create a Model for the *mytable_translations* table and use something like

```
MyTableTranslations.find(:all, :conditions => {:locale => :ru } )
```

and, like any other query, all records with the ru locate are returned.